# Is every commutative binary operation on a set with two elements associative? - Fraleigh pp27 2.28

Tags: group-theory

Prove or disprove: Every commutative binary operation on a set having just $2$ elements is associative. This is from John Fraleigh's 7th edition of A First Course in Abstract Algebra.
[image]

First of all, how did they realize this is false?

Second, how did they construct this counterexample? How did they know to start with $(a * a) * b$ and $a * (a * b)$ and know the problem is with these two ? My work here looks too complicated.

The binary operation here is given as commutative, hence $\color{green}{a*b = b*a}$.
For $a * (a * b)$, WLOG, suppose  $\color{green}{a*b = b*a = a}$.  Then $a * \color{green}{(a * b)} = a*\color{green}{a}$.

For $(a * a) * b$, WLOG, suppose $\color{blue}{a*a = b}$. Then $\color{blue}{(a*a)} * b = \color{blue}{b} * b$.

Then $\color{blue}{(a*a)} * b \neq a *\color{green}{(a * b)} \implies \color{blue}{b} * b \neq a*\color{green}{a} $.
I already picked $\color{blue}{a*a = b}$ so need $\color{blue}{b} * b = a$ for a counterexample.

Answer (score 9):

While the example can be constructed easily enough by reasoning of the sort that you used, there is another very straightforward possibility. Since the operation is commutative, we must have $a*b=b*a$. There are $2$ independent choices each for $a*a$, $a*b$, and $b*b$, and once these are made, the operation is defined. Thus, there are only $2^3=8$ commutative binary operations on $\{a,b\}$, and it’s possible simply to write them all out and check whether they are associative.

Answer (score -1):

For $(a\cdot b)\cdot a$,let $a\cdot b=b\cdot a=a$,then $(a\cdot b)\cdot a=a\cdot a$
But $a\cdot(b\cdot a)=a\cdot a$.how say associative is false?

Comment: You have only considered one case. You also have to show that $(a\cdot a)\cdot b=a\cdot (a\cdot b)$ and $(b\cdot b)\cdot a=b\cdot (b\cdot a)$. As the counterexample shows, this is not always true.